# What is the meaning of "funny sort" in Jerome K. Jerome's "Passing Of The Third Floor Back"?

Tags: meaning, jerome-k-jerome

In "Passing Of The Third Floor Back" a short story by Jerome K. Jerome [(available on Project Gutenberg)](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/865/865-h/865-h.htm) we have the following dialogue, without further explanation:

> Mrs. Pennycherry pondered. “He’s not the funny sort, is he?”
>
> Not that sort at all. Mary Jane was sure of it.

What are we meant to understand by "funny sort"?

I feel that this must be some euphemism for some undesirable and unmentionable characteristic that was clearly understood by the characters, and would have made sense to British readers in 1904.

When we meet Mrs. Pennycherry's other lodgers, it would appear she was not over particular, provided they could pay, so who might she have been reluctant to accommodate?

Comment: Maybe the rest of the context of the poem will give us some clues. Two lines isn't much to go on.

Comment: Odd and peculiar rather than suspect since the short story is about the travails of a group of characters in a boarding house and not a novel about espionage, counter-espionage and the like.

Comment: @MoziburUllah It's not a poem. Also "suspect" in British usage doesn't necessarily mean linked to spy or police activity.

Comment: @Matt Thrower: I corrected poem to short story in my next comment. The way it extract was lineated made it look like a poem. What suspect means depends upon context, given the context of the story it's unlikely to mean a 'suspicious character' and more likely odd, peculiar or eccentric.

Comment: @MoziburUllah 'suspicious' can mean odd, peculiar or eccentric in British English. This is my point.

Comment: @Matt Thrower: It can mean many things and this is why it's important to take the context of the story to decide on the most appropriate and plausible meaning - that's my point.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would take "funny sort" to be a common  euphemism for  being of eccentric behaviour, suggesting some mild  mental derangement. It could have different connotations, but from the story it seems eccentricity  was what was meant.

"funny" has two basic meanings, as per [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/funny):

> 1 Causing laughter or amusement; humorous.
>
> ‘a funny story’
>
> ‘the play is hilariously funny’
>
> 2 Difficult to explain or understand; strange or odd.
>
> ‘I had a funny feeling you'd be around’
>
> ‘it's a funny old world’
>
> ‘I do get some funny looks’
>
> ‘the funny thing is I can't remember much about it’
>
> ‘that's funny!—that vase of flowers has been moved’

Now, the phrase "a funny sort" in turn, as far as I know, only refers to the second meaning of "funny". I only found one place where this was [discussed](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-a-funny-sort-of-way.2635394/), and nowhere where it was defined.

However, if you [Google it as a phrase](https://www.google.lv/search?q=%22a%20funny%20sort%22&oq=%22a%20funny%20sort%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2223j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), you only find it with the meaning "strange" (at least that's what my results showed):

> A *funny sort* of welcome.
>   Complex new visa and immigration regulations are in danger of sending out the wrong message to foreign students and academics, reports Melanie Newman
>
> A *funny sort* of democracy.
>   Around the world, Washington endorses then deposes rulers

I have never ever hear or read anything where "a funny sort" would denote something humorous. Even if the context *would* suggest it (as I believe, it doesn't, in the JKJ story), if we were speaking about, let's say, a play:

> -- What was the play like?
>
> -- It was a funny sort of play.

I would presume the speaker means it was a strange one.

Comment: Is it definitely "funny" as in eccentric, rather than witty? I found it hard to judge from the immediate context (haven't read the whole story, but checked a few paragraphs on each side). Could you edit to expand a bit on why this interpretation is better?

Comment: I have just edited my question.  I don't really buy the eccentric explanation.

Comment: @Randal'Thor "funny sort" in my experience is an idiom. I read it occasionally in some stories and phrases like "he is the funny sort"  have always meant "he is a strange guy".

Comment: @mikado It's hard to say about a story >100 years old. It is possible, of course, that it was meant to refer to gays, or some other well defined characteristic that was undesireable at that time, as you say, but "funny sort", as far as I recall, *is* used as an idiom denoting eccentricity, at least nowadays.

Comment: @Gnudiff no doubt it might be understood to mean (innocently) eccentric, but to me the line seems to mean more.  Ephemeral, euphemistic usage is probably difficult to track down but someone might have some evidence for it.

Comment: @mikado True. However, as the story portrays Mrs. Pennycherry (at least initially) as an unpleasant person, it is also easy to presume that she is simply disapproving of strangeness of any kind,. I don't have an example on hand at the moment, but I sort of vaguely feel that this sentiment seemed to be quite common across English of that time, insofar as described in literature.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not convinced. I agree that "a funny sort of X" usually means funny as in strange, but "he's the funny sort" could have different connotations, at least to my (British English) ear. Maybe try searching for "the funny sort" instead of just "funny sort"?

Comment: @Randal'Thor It is impossible to prove a negative. ;)

Comment: It is great, if downvoting, to explain why. :-/